# Drop a Single Database table from MySql Django 1.6

Tags: mysql, django, django-1.6

I'm running a Django app on 1.6 and have a MySQL database. I'd like to delete one particular table. I've no idea how to do that? All the stackoverflow posts I found suggest dropping all the tables all together and I don't want to do that. I just want to drop one particular table. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: drop table yourtable;

Comment: where do I execute that? In the shell?

Comment: either in the shell or in mysql admin ( or any other mysql client )

Comment: I get invalid syntax in shell. Do I have to import something? I only did "from m1.models import * " and then "drop table m1.booking" Sorry I'm new to django

Comment: to clarify : when i say shell i mean execute mysql on your shell, login and then run this command. perhaps itll be easier if you use mysql admin. if you still get an error message, post it also

Comment: Are you using south (https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as migration tool ? With that you can create a migration to delete one table easily.